# Newton's method in interpolation

Tags: python, numerical-analysis, interpolation, newton-method

I've seen that in Newton's method for interpolating polynomials, the coefficients can be found algorithmically using (in Python-ish):

```
a = Y_DataPoints.copy()
m = length(X_DataPoints)
for k in range(1,m):
       a[k: m] = (a[k:m] - a[k-1]) / (X_Data[k:m] - X_Data[k-1])
```

But I don't really understand the model is subtracting all points past $k_{i}$ by $k_{i-1}$. It seems like you would only subtract $k_{i}$  by $k_{i-1}$, not the entire vector.

Can someone shed some light on this?

EDIT: Spelling

Comment: Are you talking about the method for *interpolating* datapoints by polynomials?

Comment: yes I am. I'll edit my OP

Comment: Your python code (line 3) is not valid...

Comment: I think there's another typo in the last line. Shouldn't it be *a[k:m]* instead of *a[k:length(m)]*?

Answer (score 2):

If you compute the coefficients of the Newton polynomial via [the scheme of divided differences](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynominterpolation#Bestimmung_der_Koeffizienten%3a_Schema_der_dividierten_Differenzen) linewise (what is often a good choice since then one can simply add additional data), in every line, you have to compute the differences with a fixed `X_data` point. Also, depending on how you store the "new" abscissae in `Y_DataPoints`, in every line you have to take the differences with a fixed function value.